# How can i create a method so that the below code will work

Tags: c#

//How can i create a method so that the below code will work

```
const string abc = "asduqwezxc";
foreach (var vowel in abc.SelectOnlyVowels())
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", vowel);
}
```

Comment: code start at const

Comment: highlight the code then right click and select the option that states `Refactor-> Extract Method`

Comment: I'm pretty sure he's asking how to write that `SelectOnlyVowels` string extension

Comment: `abc.Where(c => new[] { 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u' }.Contains(c))`?  You'll have to define what vowels are as there isn't anything built in to do that.

Answer (score 3):

You need to write [an extension method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb383977.aspx), like so:

```
public static class StringExt
{
    public static IEnumerable<char> SelectOnlyVowels(this string self)
    {
        return self.Where(c => "aeiou".Contains(char.ToLower(c)));
    }
}
```